# How to test a controller in angular, that gets data from an angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Real simple, I have a controller that has a property set on the scope from a service.

Controller:

```
dadApp.controller('landingController', function($scope, automationService) {
    $scope.hello = "from controller";
    $scope.foo = automationService.foo;

    // load data from service.
});
```

Service:

```
dadApp.factory('automationService', function($http) {
    var _foo = [];

    $http.get('/api/automation')
        .then(function(result) {
                angular.copy(result.data, _foo);
            },
            function() {
                alert('error');
            });

    return {
        foo: _foo
    };
});
```

In my specs/test file, how do I test this controller since it depends on a service? (FYI, the service is an ASP.NET WebAPI 2.

Here's my specs:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/app.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/services/automationService.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/controllers/landingController.js" />
'use strict';

var scope, ctrl;

describe('DAD tests', function() {
    beforeEach(module('dadApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('landingController', { $scope: scope });
    }));

    describe('landing controller tests', function() {
        describe('scope.hello', function() {
            it('should equal "from controller"', function() {
                expect(scope.hello).toEqual("from controller");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should mock your automationService and inject the mock into your controller just like you did with the scope you created.

Comment: Thanks @aet, that's what I am thinking too. Do you have a snippet for mocking a service and using it in jasmine?

Comment: We end up using a mixture of techniques, the answer I provided is just one way. You could use jasmine spyOn too, and depending on how complicated the mocking effort is, that might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var mockedFoo = {
    bar: true,
    baz: 123,
    other: "string"
};
var automationServiceMock = {
    foo: function() {
        return mockedFoo;
    }
};
describe('DAD tests', function() {
    beforeEach(module('dadApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('landingController', {
            $scope: scope, 
            automationService: automationServiceMock 
        });
    }));

    describe('landing controller tests', function() {
        describe('scope.hello', function() {
            it('should equal "from controller"', function() {
                expect(scope.hello).toEqual("from controller");
            });
        });
    });
});
```